# 配列同士で後方一致しない要素を出力したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

a,b ２つの配列のそれぞれの要素が後方一致するかを比較し、

- a,b両方で存在したもの（後方一致）
- aの配列内でbに無い要素（後方一致しないもの）
- bの配列内でaに無い要素（後方一致しないもの）

をそれぞれ出力したいです。

出力例としてはこんな感じにしたい

```
const a = ["http://abc/","http://abc/def/","http://ghi/"];
const b = ["/abc/","/def/","/jkl/"];
/*
出力例:
http://abc/ と /abc/ はOK
http://abc/def/ と /def/はOK
配列a内の差分：http://ghi/
配列b内の差分：/jkl/
*/
```

自分で書いてみたところ、a[0]とb全部→a[1]とb全部→...という風に、
後方一致するものの出力はできました。

```
for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<b.length;j++){
        if(a[i].endsWith(b[j])){
            console.log(a[i] +"と"+ b[j] +"はOK");
        }
    }
}
/*
出力:
http://abc/ と /abc/ はOK
http://abc/def/ と /def/はOK
*/
```

aの配列内でbと後方一致しないもの（http://ghi/）
bの配列内でaと後方一致しないもの（/jkl/）
をどう出力すれば良いかわかりません。

何かいい方法があれば教えていただきたいです。
（上記のfor文ももっとスマートに書ければ書き直したい...）

ご回答の程、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> aの配列内でbと後方一致しないもの（http://ghi/）

これは、aの要素それぞれに対して、bの要素と後方一致するかどうかを調べて、どれとも一致しないものだけを表示することでできます。
一番分かりやすい方法は、フラグ変数を用いてbのどれかの要素と一致したかを調べるという方法でしょう。これをやってみると次のプログラムのようになります。

```
for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    // フラグ変数（bの要素のどれかと一致したらfalseにする）
    let flag = true;
    for(let j=0;j<b.length;j++){
        if(a[i].endsWith(b[j])){
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    // bの各要素を調べ終わった後にflagがまだtrueなら、
    // これはaの配列内でbに無い要素だ
    if (flag) {
        console.log("配列a内の差分:" + a[i]);
    }
}
```

> bの配列内でaと後方一致しないもの（/jkl/）

これも同じアイデアで可能です。ただし、ループの順番を変えて、bの各要素に対してループして、その中でaの各要素を調べるという形にすればよいでしょう。

```
for(let i=0;i<b.length;i++){
    // フラグ変数（aの要素のどれかと一致したらfalseにする）
    let flag = true;
    for(let j=0;j<a.length;j++){
        if(a[j].endsWith(b[i])){
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    // aの各要素を調べ終わった後にflagがまだtrueなら、
    // これはbの配列内でaに無い要素だ
    if (flag) {
        console.log("配列b内の差分:" + b[i]);
    }
}
```

---

また、よりスマートに書く方法をいくつか紹介します。最後の例については、フラグ変数`flag`をいちいち持っておくのが嫌なので、ラベル付きfor文と`continue`文を用いて次のように書き直せます。

```
outerLoop: for(let i=0;i<b.length;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<a.length;j++){
        if(a[j].endsWith(b[i])){
            // aの要素と一致したのでこのbの要素を調べるのはやめる
            continue outerLoop;
        }
    }
    // bの各要素を調べ終わっても生き残ったので、
    // これはaの配列内でbに無い要素だ
    console.log("配列b内の差分:" + b[i]);
}
```

また、2重for文は分かりにくいので、[Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)を用いて次のように書き直すこともできます。

```
for(let i=0;i<b.length;i++){
    if (a.every(aElm => !aElm.endsWith(b[i]))) {
        // aの要素のどれとも後方一致しなかったら
        console.log("配列b内の差分:" + b[i]);
    }
}
```

一番最初の例については2重for文を書かないといけないのは仕方ありませんが、普通のfor文の代わりにfor-of文を使うと少し分かりやすくなるので紹介します。

```
for(let aElm of a){
    for(let bElm of b){
        if(aElm.endsWith(bElm)){
            console.log(aElm +"と"+ bElm +"はOK");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

処理内容を少し考えてみればわかりますが、「a全部×b全部」の総当たりをしないといけないので、メインの二重`for`ループはあまり「スマートに」しようが無い気がします。

後は一致しないものを表示する部分ですね。以下は単純に、一致したらフラグを立てて、最後にフラグが立っていない要素をまとめて表示する、なんてことをしています。

```js
const a = ["http://abc/","http://abc/def/","http://ghi/"];
const b = ["/abc/","/def/","/jkl/"];

//aと同じ長さで初期値が全部falseの配列を作る
var aHasMatch = a.map(_ => false);
//bと同じ長さで初期値が全部falseの配列を作る
var bHasMatch = b.map(_ => false);

for( let i in a ) {
    for( let j in b ) {
        if( a[i].endsWith(b[j]) ){
            console.log(a[i] +"と"+ b[j] +"はOK");
            aHasMatch[i] = true;
            bHasMatch[j] = true;
        }
    }
}
//aの中で対応するaHasMatchがfalseのものだけ集める
var aDiff = a.filter((_, i) => !aHasMatch[i]);
console.log("配列a内の差分："+aDiff.join(","));
//bの中で対応するbHasMatchがfalseのものだけ集める
var bDiff = b.filter((_, j) => !bHasMatch[j]);
console.log("配列b内の差分："+bDiff.join(","));
```

`const`や`let`を使っているので、それが大丈夫なら大抵大丈夫だろうとばかり、ブラウザの対応状況を調べずコードを書いちゃっているので、もしかしたらブラウザによっては(あなたの元のコードが動くものでも)動かないかもしれませんが、考え方としてはそのまま使えると思います。

(もっと「スマートに」書けるかもしれませんが、最近のJavaScriptには不慣れなので…。)

一つの例としてお試しください。